# WPF: Deselect all my Checkbox when one is selected

Tags: wpf, listview, checkbox

This is my first `ListView row column` that contain `CheckBox`:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="40" >
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Name="cbSelectInterface" IsThreeState="False" ></CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

How can i add the option to check only one `CheckBox` in specific `Row` and what i choose another `CheckBox` and check this control all other `CheckBox` become non selected ?

Comment: You have several CheckBoxes per row and you want to select one Check per row? Or you have one CheckBox per row and want to have one CheckBox out of all the rows?

Comment: just style the radiobuttons to look like check box then

Comment: I have one CheckBox per row.

Comment: @ Theodosius Von Richthofen: with RadioButton this behavior the same, i still can check several RadioButtons

Comment: What about binding the CheckBox's IsChecked property to the ListViewItem's IsSelected property? If SelectionMode is set to Single, then you'll only be able to select one row and one checkbox.

Comment: Can i have code example ?

Comment: use radio button groups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about binding the CheckBox's IsChecked property to the ListViewItem's IsSelected property? If SelectionMode is set to Single, then you'll only be able to select one row and one checkbox.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TestDataSource}}"
          SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="30">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,
                                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                              AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

You can then use the ListView's `SelectedItem` to know which row is the one with the checked CheckBox.

Comment: TestDataSource could not be resolved, so i left it dataList and it work fine, wha is the differences ?

Comment: Oh, it was just the source I was using for testing, it's not needed... You can use whichever ItemsSource you want.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, there is no control that automatically does what you want. However, implementing your requirement is simple, or at least, would be simple if you were using data binding as is customary in WPF applications. In that case, your view model or code behind would have an object (that would be data bound to the `ListView.ItemsSource` property) that contains all of the data items.

All you need to do when one of the `Checkbox`es is checked is to iterate through each item in the data bound collection and set their properties that are data bound to the `Checkbox` to `false`:

```
foreach (var item in YourDataBoundCollection)
{
    item.PropertyDataBoundToCheckBox = false;
}
```

If you have implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your data class as you should have, then the UI will be automatically updated.

The only remaining question is how do you know when a `CheckBox` has been checked? The simplest 'non MVVM' way would be to add a handler for the [`CheckBox.Checked` Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.checked(v=vs.110).aspx).